# Space before a position:absolute element?

Tags: css, css-position

I have an element that is absolutely positioned at the bottom of its box, and then the box itself is part of a series that are all fixed at the height of the tallest box. I am blanking on how to get some whitespace above the absolutely positioned element? [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zh2os8yt/3/) ... the "Do this" button in the tallest box needs some space above it and below the list.

I am trying to insert a line feed and set the white-space but this doesn't work.

```
.myelement:before {
    content: "\00000a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a bottom margin to your last `li` element since they are determining the height.

Add this css:

```
.providers li:last-child{
     margin-bottom:30px;   
}
```

of course that margin could be whatever you need.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zh2os8yt/5/)

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble wrapping my brain around why padding on the `ul` itself didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way – add a `padding-bottom` to your items:

```
.ListCtr {
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zh2os8yt/4/

Since your buttons contain only a small amount of text, this will work unless the screen width gets “really small”. If that’s an issue, you might want to use a bigger padding value for narrow screens using a media query.

But `flexbox` would be an even better tool to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding-bottom to your boxes. For example you can edit the .ListCtr to the following:

```
.ListCtr {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom:80px;
}
```